# creating a function for mathematical data imputation python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, replace, missing-data

I am performing a number of similar operations and I would like to write a function but not even sure how to approach this. I am calculating the values for 0 data for the following series:

- the formula is 2 * value in 2001 - value in 2002

I currently do it one by one in Python:

```
print(full_data.loc['Croatia', 'fertile_age_pct'])
print(full_data.loc['Croatia', 'working_age_pct'])
print(full_data.loc['Croatia', 'young_age'])
print(full_data.loc['Croatia', 'old_age'])

full_data.replace(to_replace={'fertile_age_pct': {0:(2*46.420061-46.326103)}}, inplace=True)
full_data.replace(to_replace={'working_age_pct': {0:(2*67.038157-66.889212)}}, inplace=True)
full_data.replace(to_replace={'young_age': {0:(2*0.723475-0.715874)}}, inplace=True)
full_data.replace(to_replace={'old_age': {0:(2*0.692245-0.709597)}}, inplace=True)
```

Data frame (full_data):

```
geo_full  year   fertile_age_pct    working_age_pct    young_age    old_age
Croatia   2000   0                  0                  0            0
Croatia   2001   46.420061          67.038157          0.723475     0.692245
Croatia   2002   46.326103          66.889212          0.715874     0.709597
Croatia   2003   46.111822          66.771187          0.706091     0.72444
Croatia   2004   45.929829          66.782133          0.694854     0.735333
Croatia   2005   45.695932          66.742514          0.686534     0.747083
```

Comment: Can you print your original dataframe (or relevant rows and columns) as well? Your current code replaces the whole column where geo_full is Croatia.

Comment: @DjerroNeth the original dataframe is really large, includes some 30 countries for 2000-2019; the problem with 0 data is only for Croatia for 2000

Comment: hi there, did you try my answer?

Comment: @RichieV yes, but ended up not using it since I dropped some of the other series with lots of data missing. Decided to do it one-by-one instead

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to fill the 0 values in year 2000 with your formula. If you have any other country in the DataFrame then it can get messy.

Assuming the year with 0's is always the first year for each country, try this:

```
full_data.set_index('year', inplace=True)
fixed_data = {}
for country, df in full_data.groupby('geo_full')[full_data.columns[1:]]:
    if df.iloc[0].sum() == 0:
        df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[1] * 2 - df.iloc[0]
    fixed_data[country] = df
fixed_data = pd.concat(list(fixed_data.values()), keys=fixed_data.keys(), names=['geo_full'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you @RichieV - there are 30 countries included in the dataset but the problem is only with Croatia, no other 0 values. I already set the index to geo_full but I suppose I can re-set it back. I followed the code you suggested but receiving error on df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[1]*2 - df.iloc[1] TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: worked well, with a small twist:                                                                        
```full_data.set_index('year', inplace=True)
fixed_data = {}
for country, df in full_data.groupby('geo_full')[full_data.columns[1:]]:
    if df.iloc[0].sum() == 0:
        df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[1] * 2 - df.iloc[0]
    fixed_data[country] = df
fixed_data = pd.concat(list(fixed_data.values()), keys=fixed_data.keys(), names=['geo_full'], axis=0)```  How do I call the function now though for the specific situation I have, i.e. filling the values for indicators fertile_age_pct etc.?

Comment: what is missing? isn't fixed_data the expected result?